# Linking eclipse project as library to Android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Eclipse has this neat feature where you can set one project to build path of another project so that you can separate the two projects as library and the application while maintaining the independence of editing these projects as desired.

This also helps as change in library project is immediately reflected onto application project

Now I want to do something similar for android studio , but the library that my android project is being built on is a java project in eclipse IDE. 
Currently what I do is make some changes in library project eclipse then export it as jar file and then import it on android studio.

This is tedious as I want to develop the library project in eclipse alongside the android project and exporting and copying over the jar files manually is slow

Is it possible to do any of the following:

1. Setup eclipse project such that its build outputs/updates a jar in the libs folder of android project each time project is built in eclipse?
2. Link the Android studio project's build path to include the eclipse project
3. Edit the java project on android studio along side the Android project and link them both

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is the official integrated development environment (IDE) for Google's Android operating system, built based on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA software. Android Studio uses Gradle

In answer to your question

1. You have to understand Build Process with gradle in Android Studio.
2. You can import your Android project.
   And Add your library as a dependency

   [Create an Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)
3. Add as a dependency for your Andriod app modules or other Java projects.

I recommend reading this site.following Site
[Projects Overview](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html)